For some reason, when I try to run my program, it can't find something called entityManagerFactory
The full project can be found on my GitHub here: https://github.com/plasmastorm36/ToDoList/
The big issue is that my application cannot find this mysterious entityManagerFactory.
I tried changing the application.properties and changing the pom.xml file to see if that would fix anything. I have also tried using autowired.
Every time I try to run it with Maven I get this error message:

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.todo.demo.service.TaskService
required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your
configuration.

The problem could be from anything at this point but here is where I think the issues may lie.
My entity class
package com.todo.demo;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
/**
 * @Author Noah Rouse
 * @email: noahrouse36@gmail.com
 * @description: this class is designed to store and represent tasks in a todo list
 */
public class Task {
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column
   private long id;
   @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
   private String description;
   @Column(name = "completed")
   private boolean completed;
   @Column(name = "priority")
   private String priority;
   @Column(name = "due_date")
   private LocalDate dueDate;
   @Column(name = "created")
   private LocalDate created;
   @Column(name = "last_updated")
   private LocalDate lastUpdated;

   public Task () {}

   public Task (final Long id, final String description, final String priority,
         final LocalDate dueDate) {
      this.id = id;
      this.completed = false;
      this.description = description;
      this.priority = priority;
      this.dueDate = dueDate;
      this.created = LocalDate.now();
      this.lastUpdated = created;
   }

   /**
    * @return task id
    */
   public long id () {
      return this.id;      
   }

   /**
    * @return description
    */
   public String description () {
      return this.description;
   }

   /**
    * set task description to new description and changes last updated value
    * @return updated description
    */
   public String description (final String description) {
      this.description = description;
      this.lastUpdated = LocalDate.now();
      return this.description;
   }

   /**
    * @return if the task is completed
    */
   public boolean completed () {
      return this.completed;
   }

   /**
    * Set completed to true or false
    * @return updated completed status
    */
   public boolean completed (final boolean completed) {
      this.completed = completed;
      this.lastUpdated = LocalDate.now();
      return this.completed;
   }

   /**
    * @return priority of task
    */
   public String priority () {
      return this.priority;
   }

   /**
    * sets task to new priority
    * @return new priority
    */
   public String priority (final String priority) {
      this.priority = priority;
      this.lastUpdated = LocalDate.now();
      return this.priority;
   }


   /**
    * @return current task due date
    */
   public LocalDate dueDate () {
      return this.dueDate;
   }

   /**
    * change due date to new local date
    * @return new due date
    */
   public LocalDate dueDate (final LocalDate dueDate) {
      this.dueDate = dueDate;
      this.lastUpdated = LocalDate.now();
      return this.dueDate;
   }

   /**
    * @return when the task was last updated
    */
   public LocalDate lastUpdated () {
      return this.lastUpdated;
   }
}

My Service class
package com.todo.demo.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.todo.demo.Task;
import com.todo.demo.repository.TaskRepository;


import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Optional;
@Service
@Transactional
public class TaskService {
   public class TaskNotFoundException extends Exception {

   }
   private final TaskRepository taskRepos;

   public TaskService (final TaskRepository taskRepository) {
      taskRepos = taskRepository;
   }

   public void updateTaskDescription (final long taskId, final String description)
         throws TaskNotFoundException {
      final Optional<Task> potentialTask = taskRepos.findById(taskId);

      if (potentialTask.isPresent()) {
         final Task task = potentialTask.get();
         task.description(description);
         taskRepos.save(task);
      } else {
         throw new TaskNotFoundException();
      }
   }

   public void updateTaskCompletion (final long taskId, final boolean completed)
         throws TaskNotFoundException {
      final Optional<Task> potentialTask = taskRepos.findById(taskId);
      
      if (potentialTask.isPresent()) {
         final Task task = potentialTask.get();
         task.completed(completed);
         taskRepos.save(task);
      } else {
         throw new TaskNotFoundException();
      }
   }

   public void updateTaskPriority (final long taskId, final String priority)
         throws TaskNotFoundException {
      final Optional<Task> potentialTask = taskRepos.findById(taskId);

      if (potentialTask.isPresent()) {
         final Task task = potentialTask.get();
         task.priority(priority);
         taskRepos.save(task);
      } else {
         throw new TaskNotFoundException();
      }
   }

   public void updateTaskDueDate (final long taskId, final LocalDate dueDate)
         throws TaskNotFoundException {
      final Optional<Task> potentialTask = taskRepos.findById(taskId);

      if (potentialTask.isPresent()) {
         final Task task = potentialTask.get();
         task.dueDate(dueDate);
         taskRepos.save(task);
      } else {
         throw new TaskNotFoundException();
      }
   }
}

my pom.xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.todo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>21</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.214</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

My application.properties file:
spring.application.name=demo

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true


Remove the spring-data-jpa and jakarta.persistence-api dependencies and add spring-boot-starter-data-jpa instead.

It's not Maven that can't find, it is your application. As M. Deinum says, you need to properly use the Spring Data JPA starter, which will define entityManagerFactory for you (it is used below the surface by Spring Data JPA to access the database).

Replace this section in your pom.xml with
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

With
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

